# MYSQL How to seach for values from one database in another database?

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql databases LookFor(ID,Term) & CText(ID,CT)
LookFor has 19200 Items (6 chars long) and CText has 200 Items (100 chars long)

I am looking for a solution to find if any of the items in the DB LookFor are contained in the DB CText.

I can do this in PHP (But it takes ages), I am wondering if it is possible to do it directly in mySQL.

Comment: I guess you mean tables LookFor and CText?
If tables, then just outer join them and if LookFor not null then these are the rows of data that are contained in CText.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't mean two tables in the same database (which seems to be what you have described).

if your two databases are on the same server you should be able to use the multi-part identifier when referencing the tables e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.LookFor LF
Join DB2.CText CT
WHERE LF.`ID` = CT.`ID`
AND LF.`From` = CT.`From`
```

the undefined join will then only show results which are not null in either table.